# Use a no-ip config on a Huawei HG532c

Tags: router, noip

I want to use my new no-ip.org account and I want to refresh the IP where is point my domain with my router (without using the client software).

I think I am configuring good all the settings, this is my config:

```
Service provider: others
Wan connction: nas_8_35
Host: <host>    
Domain: <domain>
user name: <user>
Password: <pass>
server address : dynupdate.no-ip.com
server port: 8245
service name: No-Ip.org
protocol: GNUDip.http
```

I am using a Huawei HG532c, and the problem I get is that the IP on the no-ip.org host manager pannel doesn´t refresh when I force the router to get a new one, and making a ping to . allways goes to the old IP.

Any Idea??

Thank you very much.

PD: I tried using on "user name" tag, my user name on my sign up, and too the email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this link : http://www.talktalkmembers.com/t5/Unlimited-Broadband/DDNS-settings-on-HG533/td-p/844595

It says: ...Unfortunately, there is a bug in the GNUDip.http implementation on all Huewai TT routers - the salt, sign and pass parameters are not correctly passed to the server - they are sent, but missing the last character in each case. So, with an incomplete password hash sent by the router, the remote server will be unable to verify it Smiley Sad. That's probably why you're having trouble with it.

Then: ...
on ‎11-04-2015 02:11 PM

I notice the bugs in the GNUDip.http implementation are fixed in the HG533 v1.18t firmware - that is the salt, sign and pass parameters are now passed in full, whereas these missed the last character with v1.15t. Also, v1.18t now correctly only accesses the update script when the IP address has really been changed, and not repeatedly forever every minute or so as was the case with v1.15t.

If you can change the firmware good. Try and let us know.

Comment: Thanks @LosMontons. I had seen this issue on forums, and I decided to install the no-ip software on a raspberry, it works so I´ll no test anymore on my router.